# OutOfMemory with Ansible PowerShell Automation

Tags: powershell, automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, winrm

I have a PowerShell script which performs a lot of in-memory data manipulation. It is used in a configuration process I am automating with Ansible Playbooks. When the script is run manually on the server, it finishes successfully, and the correct changes are observed. However, when I run the same script through Ansible, an `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown by PowerShell.

I've tried increasing PowerShell's allocated memory well beyond the expected size using,

```
Set-Item vsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB [memsize]
```

This resulted in the same error. However, if I run the script on the server once before triggering the playbook, it seems to work, until I restart the machine.

For Ansible, my remote connection is configured using WinRM.

Comment: hey, i found this [link](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2014/03/out-of-memory-exception-in-powershell/) maybe you found the same one :D But the last sentence is very important - _Last: Restart the winrm service… and you’re done _ - did you restart the service?

Comment: @Eldo.Ob that page seems to help! I've only carried out one test so far (the script takes a while to terminate), but it succeeded.

For anyone interested, I fixed the issue with:

`Set-Item vsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB [memsize]`

`net stop winrm`

`net start winrm`

Comment: okay tell me if it definetly works. :)

Comment: @Eldo.Ob I tried reverting the changes after a few successful tests, and the bug came back, so I'm pretty certain your fix works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running PS3, have you tried [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2842230) as suggested in the Ansible [Windows docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#windows-system-prep)?

Comment: This seems like the same issue, but the machines in my test environment don't support the patch. If anyone else finds this post, this is probably worth trying first. However, I can't verify it.

If it doesn't work, the fix by Eldo.Ob in the comments should resolve it.